# Positing TextViews and EditTexts when they have been added dynamically

Tags: java, android, textview, android-edittext

I am trying to position TextViews, EditTexts and a button, however they all they all keep getting squished together. They are all being added onto the layout dynamically, is there any way I can position them each with a TextView and then a EditText underneath it. If possible would someone be able to point me in the right direction.

This is what I've got so far:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle           savedInstanceState)
{
    //putting the layout on xml page
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = container.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int total;

    width= width/6;
    height = height/6;


    //type of layout to be used
    RelativeLayout relle = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.heloo);

    int prevTextViewId = 0;

    String [] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.income_page);

    for (String anArray : array)
    {
        final TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        final EditText editText = new EditText(getActivity());
        final Button submit = new Button(getActivity());

        //setting text
        textView.setText(anArray);
        editText.setText(R.string.pound_sign);
        submit.setText(R.string.submit);

        int curTextViewId = prevTextViewId + 1;
        textView.setId(curTextViewId);

        curTextViewId += 1;

        editText.setId(curTextViewId);
        final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, prevTextViewId);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        editText.setLayoutParams(params);
        //textView.setTextColor(R.color)

        prevTextViewId = curTextViewId;
        relle.addView(textView, params);
        relle.addView(editText, params);
        relle.addView(submit, width, height);
    }//for

    return view;
}//view oncreate
```

This is the way it's appearing on my emulator
[image: way its appearing]

Answer (score 1):

There is another method to add view along with index in which position you want to add along with params

```
addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

So you can use this. :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, So you just check the id of the views and make sure layout params are added correctly.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.view_below_id);

viewToLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams );
```

Comment: I've uploaded an image of how it is appearing on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Change parent of you layout to LinearLayout with orientation set as vertical and then add TextView and EditText's in the sequence you want them to get displayed.

Comment: How would I go about adding the TextViews and EditTexts that way?

Comment: Take a reference of the Linear Layout in your layout and then start adding textviews and edittexts using linearlayout.addView(view);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0);
TextView textView;
textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

// Also add some padding to the views so that there's some space b/w them
textView.setPadding(l, t, r, b);

//If you want to give padding in dp you using//displayMetrics.scaledDensity;
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);